# Use artifact version number in OpenAPI spec definition

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a maven project with my API definition using the OpenaAPI v3 specification.

I generate the code using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin and all works fine. I'm also able to access the swagger-ui and view and test my API.

The problem is that I don't want to maintain the version number twice. So I'd like to refer the version number from my maven pom in my api spec instead of duplicating it with the risk of it getting outdated.

I've tried maven resource filtering, which seems to work. Since the yaml file in the target folder gets it nicely replaced when I put `${project.version}` in the version field in the spec, but when I open the swagger-ui it prints "${project.version}" literally instead of the actual version.

This is the plugin config from my pom:

```
<build>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
          <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.build.resources[0].directory}/spec.yml</inputSpec>
                <ignoreFileOverride>${project.build.resources[0].directory}/.openapi-codegen-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                <language>spring</language>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <configOptions>
                  <!-- Use the newer java.time package instead of outdated java.util-->
                  <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
                <apiPackage>${default.package}.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>${default.package}.model</modelPackage>
                <invokerPackage>${default.package}.invoker</invokerPackage>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
       ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my spec.yml:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: ${project.version}
...
```

Comment: I don't have a solution to your question, but I think in `<inputSpec>` you're pointing at the `src/main/resources` file rather than the `target/` file. You can see this by running `mvn help:effective-pom`. The second issue is that the `generate-sources` phase runs before `process-resources`, so the `target/` file does not exist when openapi-generator runs. You can see this with `mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:list`. You may be able to define a `<plugin>` block for maven-resources-plugin bound to the `generate-sources` phase so that it executes before openapi-generator?

Comment: Thanks, will give that a shot :-)

Comment: It worked, posted solution as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @bcoughlan I was able to get the maven-resources-plugin working as desired.

Now it takes filters the *yml file from the src/main/resources folder and replaces the ${project.version} placeholder during the `generates-sources` phase. Because the openapi-generator-maven-plugin executes in the same phase and is defined later, it will be executed after the resource filtering and will operate on the api spec in the target folder as a result of `${project.build.outputDirectory}/spec.yml`

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Codegen plugin for api. Depends on maven-resources-plugin to have executed in the generate-sources phase! -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.build.outputDirectory}/spec.yml</inputSpec>
                <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.openapi-codegen-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
              <language>spring</language>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <configOptions>
                <!-- Use the newer java.time package instead of outdated java.util-->
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
              </configOptions>
              <apiPackage>${default.package}.api</apiPackage>
              <modelPackage>${default.package}.model</modelPackage>
              <invokerPackage>${default.package}.invoker</invokerPackage>
              <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Note: the openapi-generator-maven-plugin is almost the same as the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin. More about the difference can be found here: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/fork-qna

Note 2: When using **spring-boot** parent pom, you inherit resource.delimeter=@ property and `${project.version}` notation no longer works. So replacing the placeholder with `@project.version@` should fix that.

Comment: Worth mentioning: When two plugins are bound to the same lifecycle phase, they are executed in the order declared in the POM. So this block must be declared before the openapi-generator block

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the answer and code example.